# Extract several lines from large text file

Tags: text-processing, large-files

I have a large text file.

I need to **quickly** pull a bunch of lines, say from #14600 to #14700, from this file, as a separate file.

How it could be done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
sed -n 14600,14700p filename > newfile
```

Where:

- `p` : Print out the pattern space (to the standard output). This command is usually only used in conjunction with the -n command-line option.
- `n` : If auto-print is not disabled, print the pattern space, then, regardless, replace the pattern space with the next line of input. If there is no more input then sed exits without processing any more commands.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `sed` to get those results:

```
sed -n '14600,14700p;14700q' largefile
```

Comment: For me this command worked a bit slower than the one without `;LINEq` (when extracting single line 26995107 from a 27169334-line file). Why did you include this `q` part?

Answer (score 1):

Old-style:

```
tail -n +14600 filename | head -n 100
```

and less-memory-save variant:

```
head -n 14700 filename | tail -n +14600
```

Answer (score 0):

using awk

```
awk 'NR>=14600&&NR<=147000' filename
```